# How many $1 \times 4$ collage designs if there are $4$ frames of size $1 \times 1$ and $5$ frames of size $1 \times 2$?

Tags: combinatorics

The question I am stuck on is:

Let a(n) be the number of collage designs of size 1xn. There are 4 frames of size 1×1 and 5 frames of size 1x2, how many collage designs can be formed of size 1x4?

According to my textbook the answer is 521. However, I cannot work out how to get there. If I do not take into account orientation then I have (4P4) + (9P3) + (5P2) - I used permutations because presumably with collage order matters. 4P4 comes from the idea of using the 4 1x1s to create a 1x4. 9P3 comes from using 2 1x1s and 1 2x1 and 5P2 from using 2 2x1s. However, this leaves me with 24 + 504 + 20 which is 548 not 521. Then I thought 9P3 could be wrong thinking that first you need 4P2 and then 5P1 and then somehow combine this to be xP3...I am not sure how you would work this.

Can anybody help me see how they have got 521.

Many thanks.

Emma

Comment: What is a "collage design"?

Comment: I assume a collage as in art (a mix of images), the question is very badly phrased, I think that is part of the problem. My teacher just told me they don't want to help me too much, i.e. they won't help me!

Comment: Well, without a mathematical definition, I don't see how anyone can help.  I've never heard the term used in mathematics.  In case it helps, by googling, I found [this](https://www.studocu.com/en-us/messages/question/2995595/let-an-be-the-number-of-collage-designs-of-size-1xn-there-are-4-frames-of-size-11) which looks similar to your question, but which also includes no definitions.

Comment: I think it's irrelevant what collage design is you could just replace it with the word brick. As in Let a(n) be the number of bricks of size 1xn. It's just a "real world" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just guessing that we are given that there are four $1\times 1$ objects and exactly five $1\times 2$ objects, and no other building blocks.

This would be right model if, say, we had four distinct colors of $1\times 1$ blocks and five distinct colors of $1\times 2$ blocks (for a total of nine distinct colors).  Of course, the OP might have had something very different in mind.

If we work recursively, let $a_n$ be the answer we seek.  Then $a_1=4$.  Now, $a_2\neq 5$ (this was the source of an error in my first posted "solution").  There are $5$ primitive blocks of size $1\times 2$ but of course you can make a $1\times 2$ pattern out of two $1\times 1$ blocks.  Thus $$a_2=5+4^2=21$$

Now, for $n>2$, we note that the first block must be either a $1\times 1$ or a $1\times 2$ block and we deduce the recursion $$a_n=4a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2}$$

This gives us the sequence $$\{4,21,104, 521, 2604, \cdots, \}$$

and confirms $a_4=521$.

Comment: I was able to obtain the stated answer by assuming that the frames could be repeated, which gives four choices for each $1 \times 1$ frame and five choices for each $1 \times 2$ frame.

Answer (score 1):

To get the stated answer of $521$, it is necessary to assume that frames can be repeated, which was not clear from the question.  Under that assumption, there are $4$ choices for each $1 \times 1$ frame and $5$ choices for each $1 \times 2$ frame.

Four $1 \times 1$ frames:  There are four choices for each $1 \times 1$ frame, so there are $4^4$ such sequences.

One $1 \times 2$ frame and two $1 \times 1$ frame:  There are three ways to place the $1 \times 2$ frame since it must begin in one of the first three positions, $5$ ways to select the $1 \times 2$ frame, and four choices for each of the $1 \times 1$ frames.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4^2$ such sequences.

Two $1 \times 2$ frames:  There are $5$ choices for each of the two $1 \times 2$ frames, so there are $5^2$ such sequences.

*Total:*  Since the three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of possible $1 \times 4$ collage designs that can be formed is
$$4^4 + 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4^2 + 5^2 = 521$$

Comment: @lulu The question asks for the number of ways of filling a $1 \times 4$ space.  I am assuming that there are four different designs for a $1 \times 1$ frame and five different designs for a $1 \times 2$ frame and that each design may be repeated in the collage as often as desired.  I made these assumptions since it was the only way I could obtain the stated answer.  If my interpretation is sound, then the wording of the question was awful.

Comment: Right, misread.  In that case, the question is the same as the one I linked to (though they get a different result).  It seems your interpretation coincides with mine...But in that case, what's wrong with my recursion?  The leftmost frame must be either $1\times 1$ or $1\times 2$ ($4$ options in the first case and $5$ in the second) and then you are left with a smaller problem.  Thus $a_n=4\times a_{n-1}+5\times a_{n-2}$?

Comment: Ah, I see. $a_2\neq 5$.  $a_2=5+16$ as you can make the $1\times 2$ blocks out of two $1\times 1$ blocks.

Comment: @lulu With that correction, our answers agree.

Comment: Exactly, sorry for my prior errors.

Comment: Amazing, thank you both for all your effort!